# magento 2 - how to insert message after shipping charges in cart summary

Tags: magento2

[image: Cart Summary Page]

How to add custom text “Add items of Rs. X more for free delivery” below shipping charges in cart summary section.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/shipping.html:13

Answer (score 0):

You can check Below Extension

[FreeShipping Progress-Bar Extension](https://github.com/christophermallory/magento2-freeshipping-progress-bar)

**Note:** check for extension's [configuration](https://github.com/christophermallory/magento2-freeshipping-progress-bar#how-to-configure)